# Why am i still getting an undefined reference to timer_create() when i have included -lrt?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, undefined-reference

```
marteli@marteli-Aspire-E5-575G:~/Downloads/Lab06$ make all
gcc -c -g -Wall -o scheduler.o scheduler.c
scheduler.c: In function ‘update_run_time’:
scheduler.c:47:37: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘clock_gettime’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  if (clock_gettime( CLOCK_REALTIME, &final)== -1)
                                     ^
In file included from scheduler.c:6:0:
/usr/include/time.h:342:12: note: expected ‘struct timespec *’ but argument is of type ‘struct timespec **’
 extern int clock_gettime (clockid_t __clock_id, struct timespec *__tp) __THROW;
            ^
scheduler.c: In function ‘update_wait_time’:
scheduler.c:71:37: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘clock_gettime’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  if (clock_gettime( CLOCK_REALTIME, &final)== -1)
                                     ^
In file included from scheduler.c:6:0:
/usr/include/time.h:342:12: note: expected ‘struct timespec *’ but argument is of type ‘struct timespec **’
 extern int clock_gettime (clockid_t __clock_id, struct timespec *__tp) __THROW;
            ^
scheduler.c: In function ‘main’:
scheduler.c:375:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘print_help’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   print_help(argv[0]);
   ^
gcc -c -g -Wall -o worker.o worker.c
gcc -c -g -Wall -o list.o list.c
list.c: In function ‘print_list’:
list.c:90:19: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
   printf("0x%X,", (unsigned int)le->info);
                   ^
gcc -g -lpthread -lrt -Wall -o scheduler scheduler.o worker.o list.o
scheduler.o: In function `init_sched_queue':
/home/marteli/Downloads/Lab06/scheduler.c:89: undefined reference to `sem_init'
/home/marteli/Downloads/Lab06/scheduler.c:96: undefined reference to `timer_create'
scheduler.o: In function `resume_worker':
/home/marteli/Downloads/Lab06/scheduler.c:112: undefined reference to `pthread_kill'
scheduler.o: In function `cancel_worker':
/home/marteli/Downloads/Lab06/scheduler.c:126: undefined reference to `pthread_kill'
scheduler.o: In function `suspend_worker':
/home/marteli/Downloads/Lab06/scheduler.c:169: undefined reference to `pthread_kill'
scheduler.o: In function `clean_up':
/home/marteli/Downloads/Lab06/scheduler.c:287: undefined reference to `sem_destroy'
scheduler.o: In function `create_workers':
/home/marteli/Downloads/Lab06/scheduler.c:312: undefined reference to `pthread_create'
/home/marteli/Downloads/Lab06/scheduler.c:316: undefined reference to `pthread_detach'
scheduler.o: In function `scheduler_run':
/home/marteli/Downloads/Lab06/scheduler.c:341: undefined reference to `timer_settime'
scheduler.o: In function `start_scheduler':
/home/marteli/Downloads/Lab06/scheduler.c:356: undefined reference to `pthread_create'
scheduler.o: In function `main':
/home/marteli/Downloads/Lab06/scheduler.c:375: undefined reference to `print_help'
/home/marteli/Downloads/Lab06/scheduler.c:383: undefined reference to `print_help'
/home/marteli/Downloads/Lab06/scheduler.c:409: undefined reference to `pthread_join'
worker.o: In function `cancel_thread':
/home/marteli/Downloads/Lab06/worker.c:16: undefined reference to `sem_post'
worker.o: In function `enter_scheduler_queue':
/home/marteli/Downloads/Lab06/worker.c:50: undefined reference to `sem_wait'
worker.o: In function `start_worker':
/home/marteli/Downloads/Lab06/worker.c:95: undefined reference to `pthread_sigmask'
/home/marteli/Downloads/Lab06/worker.c:105: undefined reference to `pthread_sigmask'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:11: recipe for target 'scheduler' failed
make: *** [scheduler] Error 1
marteli@marteli-Aspire-E5-575G:~/Downloads/Lab06$ ^C
marteli@marteli-Aspire-E5-575G:~/Downloads/Lab06$ make all
gcc -g -pthread -lrt -Wall -o scheduler scheduler.o worker.o list.o
scheduler.o: In function `init_sched_queue':
/home/marteli/Downloads/Lab06/scheduler.c:96: undefined reference to `timer_create'
scheduler.o: In function `scheduler_run':
/home/marteli/Downloads/Lab06/scheduler.c:341: undefined reference to `timer_settime'
scheduler.o: In function `main':
/home/marteli/Downloads/Lab06/scheduler.c:375: undefined reference to `print_help'
/home/marteli/Downloads/Lab06/scheduler.c:383: undefined reference to `print_help'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:11: recipe for target 'scheduler' failed
make: *** [scheduler] Error 1
```

The first compilation with  all the undefined references was when the makefile ran -lpthread. When i changed -lpthread to -pthread i got better results, but im still getting undefined references. I couldn't find anything for "print_help", but i understand that -lrt should fix the issue that im having now but you can see that it is already included in the make.
EDIT: after fixing my errors for clock_gettime(), i compile and this is the new log

```
marteli@marteli-Aspire-E5-575G:~/Downloads/Lab06$ make all
gcc -c -g -Wall -o scheduler.o scheduler.c
scheduler.c: In function ‘main’:
scheduler.c:375:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘print_help’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   print_help(argv[0]);
   ^
gcc -g -pthread -lrt -Wall -o scheduler scheduler.o worker.o list.o
scheduler.o: In function `init_sched_queue':
/home/marteli/Downloads/Lab06/scheduler.c:96: undefined reference to `timer_create'
scheduler.o: In function `scheduler_run':
/home/marteli/Downloads/Lab06/scheduler.c:341: undefined reference to `timer_settime'
scheduler.o: In function `main':
/home/marteli/Downloads/Lab06/scheduler.c:375: undefined reference to `print_help'
/home/marteli/Downloads/Lab06/scheduler.c:383: undefined reference to `print_help'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:11: recipe for target 'scheduler' failed
make: *** [scheduler] Error 1
```

UPDATE 2: After omitting print_help, here is the terminal

```
marteli@marteli-Aspire-E5-575G:~/Downloads/Lab06$ make all
gcc -c -g -Wall -o scheduler.o scheduler.c
gcc -g -pthread -lrt -Wall -o scheduler scheduler.o worker.o list.o
scheduler.o: In function `init_sched_queue':
/home/marteli/Downloads/Lab06/scheduler.c:96: undefined reference to `timer_create'
scheduler.o: In function `scheduler_run':
/home/marteli/Downloads/Lab06/scheduler.c:341: undefined reference to `timer_settime'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:11: recipe for target 'scheduler' failed
make: *** [scheduler] Error 1
```

Comment: undefined reference is a linker problem. You should first sort out your compilation problems. Those warnings should be resolved before wondering about linker problems.

Comment: "scheduler.c:47:37: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘clock_gettime’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  .....  expected ‘struct timespec *’ but argument is of type ‘struct timespec **’" This is a serious compilation problem.

Comment: Ok, will fix these

Comment: Ok so i solved all issues except this one that remains which says: 
scheduler.c:375:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘print_help’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   print_help(argv[0]);
This was provided to me, however, i did not modify this so it should run fine.

Comment: Where did you get this function? Didn't it come with some header file holding a declaration of it? As the linker also complains about undefined reference to `print_help` there might be an additional problem.

Comment: Yeah it didnt, the only appearance it makes is twice and its being used. No declaration. I just triple checked all files. Really interesting. Anyways, check the main post edit to see the new log of terminal when i omit the two occurrences of print_help

Comment: Did you read R..'s answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Libraries have to go *after* the object files that depend on them on the compiler command line, not at the beginning. So:

```
gcc -g -Wall -o scheduler scheduler.o worker.o list.o -lpthread -lrt
```

Aside from that, you have a number of serious bugs in the source that you need to correct (see the warnings) before your program will work.

Comment: This worked, So the make file i was given also did not work. Ok thank you very much.

Comment: @RobertBedrosian then you might accept that answer.